# Django multiple clients deployment solutions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a Django app where there are several "user spaces" or "client domains". I was wondering how I could separate each clients from accessing other's data ? So far I have come up with several options :

- Distribute one project per client with their own database
- Keep one database and one django running (two options)
- a) Add some top level table with some ID to be referenced in **each** model. But then how do I restrict someone from impersonnating someone else's ID and access their data ?
- b) Build some Authorization layer on top of requests using a header or some query param to help discriminate which data the user can acces (but I don't really know how to do so)

What is the state of the art in the domain of multiple clients using a same Django app ? Are my solutions appropriate and if so, how do I implement them ?

I have seen few related posts / articles on internet so I'm resorting to ask here.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Search for multi-tenant Django app to find other questions/articles about the subject.

Comment: [This book](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/) in particular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-tenant SAAS in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771345/multi-tenant-saas-in-django)

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten ! I'm closing this issue since it's been answered already